# Difference between on() and direct event binding

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage with jQuery (it seems that version does not matter) on Chrome. The page is fully loaded. I'm writing this in the Chrome console:

```
$(document).on('ready', () => {console.log('Hello');});
```

I get no 'Hello' in the console. However when writing this:

```
$(document).ready(() => {console.log('Hello');});
```

'Hello' is in the console now.

There is nothing special about that in the documentation, so why it is working in such a way? I've always thought that the `on()` function is just a syntax sugar.

Comment: jQuery's `on()` function does not introduce any new functionality that did not already exist, it is just an attempt to standardize event handling in jQuery

Comment: This was also my intuition - but why there is such a difference?

Comment: `ready` is not an *event* - it's `$(document).ready()`.  It's like asking why you can't do `$(document).on("fadeIn"...`

Comment: @freedomn-m is correct. However to answer your general point, ie. What's the difference between `click()` and `on('click')`, there isn't one. All shortcut methods call `on()` internally.

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> There is also $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of
>   jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0. Note that if the DOM becomes
>   ready before this event is attached, the handler will not be executed.

I fail to understand what you mean by "Nothing special about that in documentation, so why it is working in such a way? I've always thought that on() function is just a syntax sugar"

Since it was stated quite clearly. Unless you're using jQuery < 3.0.

Alternatively, you could use:

```js
$(function(){
   console.log('Hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not using new jQuery - and don't need to use, I have asked it just out of curiosity :) 

by that quote I  mean, that there is nothing in documentation about difference between binding with on() and directly using function

Comment: There isn't a difference between directly binding and using `on` for *events* - but document ready is not an *event* you can bind to.  As confirmed in this answer.  If you asked the question with an actual event, the answer would be different, but you've asked why `$(document).on("ready"...` doesn't work - and it doesn't work because it's not an event.

Comment: Also, it deprecated in 1.8 which was released in 2012 and then removed in 3.0 which was released June 2016 - so hardly "new jquery".  Perhaps you could let us know which outdated version of jquery you *are* using?